# Automatically creating unique id

Tags: vba, excel

Im still very much a novice so be nice if I'm asking a silly question but this is my issue at the moment.  I'm starting to create a database in excel for a large archive collection using a user form for the data inputting.  The simple bit is that to help identify each item in the collection I want to give each item its own ID.  The harder bit is that I want the ID to also include a prefix that makes it clear what sort of item it is.  For example the follow prefixes;

```
Description  |  Prefix
-----------------------
Newsletter   |  NEW

Minutes      |  Min

Photograph   |  Pho
```

and to add to the challenge is to have the ID to be sequential under its own prefix (they by not be grouped together though) so the list of IDs could end up like this;

```
NEW1
NEW2
PHO1
PHO2
PHO3
MIN1
NEW3
MIN2
```

IF you can suggest anything to help me achieve this i would be most grateful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes a form with a `Listbox` that has the three choices, a `Button` to generate the next record ID and a `Textbox` to display it.

It assumes that the existing IDs are in Column A of the ActiveSheet when the form is activated:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
With Me.ListBox1
    .AddItem "PHO"
    .AddItem "NEW"
    .AddItem "MIN"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Category As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Category = Me.ListBox1.Value
Me.TextBox1 = Me.ListBox1 & Application.Evaluate("=MAX(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE('" & ws.Name & "'!A1:A10," & """" & Category & """" & ","""")*1,0))") + 1
End Sub
```

It uses Application.Evaluate, which evaluates an array formula as if it was entered into a cell. If the formula was entered into a cell and there were values in A1:A10, and you'd selected "NEW" in the listbox, it would look like this:

[image]

And here's the result in the form:

[image]

Comment: +1, Doug, I would change `SUBSTITUTE(" & ws.Name & "!A1:A10` to `SUBSTITUTE('" & ws.Name & "'!A1:A10` for case when sheet name contains spaces:)

Comment: @simoco, good point. I'm not at a computer. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

In a database, it is really best to make your ID code be completely free of meaning. That is, do not include the "item type" as a part of your unique ID. It should be a field of its own. The ID code should be **nothing** more than a unique identifier.